# How to add programmatically generated gallery to tab layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

I write a method to generate gallery at run time.

```
private Gallery createGallery(ImageAdapter imageAdapter) {

    Gallery sampleGallery = new Gallery(getApplicationContext());
    sampleGallery.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    sampleGallery.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_VERTICAL);
    sampleGallery.setSpacing(5);
    sampleGallery.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    sampleGallery.setSelection(1);
    return sampleGallery;

}
```

Then I create a galley and try to set it to a Tab Layout.

```
final TabHost mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    mTabHost.setup();
    Gallery tabGallery = createGallery(brkingNewAdapter); // my image adapter
    tabGallery.setId(R.id.gallery_1);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("TAB 1")
            .setContent(R.id.gallery_1));
```

**R.id.gallery_1** is defined as mentions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216294/android-programatically-add-id-to-r-id).

I get a exception as follows.

> Could not create tab content because could not find view with id 2130968576

Any help on this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [TabContentFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabContentFactory.html).

The solution for you would be to implement `TabContentFactory` and return the `Gallery` instance in the `createTabContent` method and use `setContent(TabHost.TabContentFactory contentFactory)` method in `addTab`.

```
class GalleryContentFactory implements TabContentFactory{
    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    public GalleryContentFactory(ImageAdapter imageAdapter){
        this.imageAdapter = imageAdapter;
    }
    public View createTabContent(String tag){
        Gallery sampleGallery = new Gallery(getApplicationContext());
        sampleGallery.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        sampleGallery.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_VERTICAL);
        sampleGallery.setSpacing(5);
        sampleGallery.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        sampleGallery.setSelection(1);
        return sampleGallery;
    }
}
```

and for adding to the tab:

```
GalleryContentFactory galleryFactory = new GalleryContentFactory(brkingNewAdapter);
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("TAB 2")
            .setContent(galleryFactory));
```